# How can I use Rhino Mocks to mock a MEF export?

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks, mef

With reference to the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF), I'm trying to work out how to create clean tests with mocks.

I have an exported component which has three **private** imports. Each imported object (field) needs to be mocked. Given that the CompositionContainer uses fancy reflection tactics to set imported private fields of composable parts, even in unit tests I will need to use the container to set those field values.

How do I tell the container at run time to accept a dynamic object I've created with Rhino Mocks as a valid export so that it can be used to satisfy the imports in the component I'm testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My question has been answered [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=55271).

---

Hi Nathan

There's a couple of different options here.

1. Using a batch, you can call the AddExportedObject method to add a mock instance to the container. AddExportedObject allows you to specify the contract for the instance that you are adding. i.e. batch.AddExportedObject(mockLogger, typeof(ILogger));
2. You an also create a custom export provider to allow you add mock instances. If you follow this link, here are some utils that I use. http://pastie.org/467842. Within you'll find a FakeExportProvider, along with FakeExportDefinitions. The FakeExportDefinitions take a func for the instance. This means you can pass it an instance, or even directly create a mock.

Here's sample code to illustrate usage.

```
    protected override void Context()
    {
        MockCache = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICache>();
        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, object> ()
        var cacheDefinition = new FakeInstanceExportDefinition(typeof(ICache), MockCache, metadata);
        FakeProvider = new FakeExportProvider(f => ((FakeInstanceExportDefinition)f).Instance);
        FakeProvider.AddExportDefinitions(cacheDefinition);
        CacheExport = FakeProvider.GetExport<ICache>();
    }
```

Now above I am querying the export provider directly. However, our container allows passing in an export provider in it's construction. So you can do this...

var container = new CompositionContainer(null, FakeProvider).

HTH
Glenn